# Did not show the keyboard correctly in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, keyboard

I can not write because of the keyboard in the back, and I want it to appear in the foreground so I can write.

[image: Where is the keyboard]

What is the solution ?

Comment: can you add some code as well, how you are creating this login view?

Comment: **Code here**   [link](http://www.highwaystech.com/code.html)

Answer (score 4):

Don’t use an alert view for this—they cover the keyboard if they’re too big. Either put your web view inside whatever view you’re currently showing the alert from, or create a simple view controller containing the web view and present that instead.

Comment: this is your answer @Highways Tech

Comment: **Did you mean that it is impossible the emergence of keyboard**

Comment: Or in iOS 5 use `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`. to gather the data.